# Is it possible to use watchOS 3 vertical detail paging with a page-based interface?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, wkinterfacetable, watchos-3

I am looking to update my watchOS app with the latest watchOS 3 improvements, but I am running into an issue getting the new WKInterfaceTable vertical paging to work. It seems that vertical detail paging requires you to use the hierarchical navigation structure throughout your app.

When I remove all but 1 of my InterfaceControllers and use a push segue from my tables, the paging works as expected. However, if I instead use a push segue from within a page-based interface, nothing happens. When I switch that to a modal segue, the segue itself works but the vertical paging is not enabled then.

Any solutions other than completely switching my apps navigation to get to use this nice watchOS 3 improvement?

Answer (score 3):

According to couple WWDC 2016 videos like [Quick Interaction Techniques for watchOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/211/)
 and [Architecting for Performance on watchOS 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/227/) you need to

- Enable the Vertical Detail Paging checkbox in your table inspector.
- Use segues from your table to detail interface.
- Make sure the detail interface fits screen height.

So yes, you have to use hierarchical navigation structure (more precisely tables) to take advantage of the new detail paging API.